# GCM Push Notifications using Topics and ASP.NET with c#

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, json, google-cloud-messaging

right now I am trying to have it so that my `ASP.net` page will send the `POST` request when I click the button. Everything I have researched has brought up results using the registration tokens to send notifications to all devices, but I want to use topics instead.

I used [this](http://dotnetprojectsourcecode.blogspot.com/2014/02/google-gcm-send-notification-to-android.html) code and it all works fine if I use the registration token. I think the problem I am having is figuring out how to format the `"PostData"` so that it uses topics instead.

I've tried changing `"registration_id="` to `"to="` and use `/topics/global` instead of `RegId`, but that didn't seem to do anything.

If worse comes to worse, I can just figure out how to store the registration tokens and use those, but I would much rather continue using topics (I already had them working with a `PHP POST` request).

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. The weird thing is that I'm pretty sure I already tried formatting it like this and it didn't work, but now it works. It's definitely exactly what I thought it should be, since it looks exactly like the examples Google provides.

```
string postData =
            "{ \"to\": \"" + topic + "\", " +
            "\"data\": {\"message\": \"" + message + "\"}}";
```